# How to insert a substring in a string ever 8 characters and continue on in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

Editted: I see now that it breaks every 3-4 letters because it is counting the commas. How do I also get it to ignore the commas?

I have a string of letters and every 8 letters I want to insert a substring of 8 zeros. So if my string input is 'H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,l,d', I want my output to look like 'H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,l,d'. This is what I have so far but I see it breaking after I iterate through like 3-4 letters.

```
x = 'H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,l,d,I,t,I,s,A,G,o,o,d,D,a,y' 
count = 0
for ele in x:
    if count == 8:
        x = x[:count] + ',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,' + x[count:]
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
```

Comment: Why do you have commas separating the characters?

Comment: `s = ''.join([x.replace(',', '') for x in s])` to remove commas

Comment: Hi they are separated by commas to simplify the example. The data  I actually have isn't hello world. The application I have is a little more complicated it converts a string input from ascii to binary and pretty much I want to say after every 8 bits insert a bunch of 0s so I can see the break in characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to keep the commas for my application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a comma behind every character, in your example you actually insert the zeros after 16 characters. An easy way to do that is the following:

```
distance = 16
insertion = '0,' * 8
x = 'H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,l,d,I,t,I,s,A,G,o,o,d,D,a,y' 

parts = [x[i:i+distance] for i in range(0, len(x), distance)]
result = insertion.join(parts)
```

Result will be:
`'H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,l,d,I,t,I,s,A,G,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,o,o,d,D,a,y'`

Also a short warning: In your example code, you loop over the elements of x but in the loop, you modifiy x. You should never modify the variable (iterable) you are looping over. Rather, if you want to follow your approach, you should create a new variable as an empty string `y = ''` and then concatenate your new strings in the for-loop to y. In the end, you can override x with y.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tip! It dropped into my more specific application perfectly